# Can I Turn On the Linux Development Environment on Chromebook as a Guest User

Tags: chromebook

When using my Chromebook as a guest, I do not see the *Developers* Option under *Advanced* Settings, as per the [documentation](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/9145439). Is this because I am not signed into a google account? I do not see that stated as a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You must sign in to a Google account to enable this feature. After that, the *Settings > Advanced > Developers > Linux development environment* option will become available. This is not visible when using the Chromebook as a guest user.